# Sorting dictionary according to lambda: handling exceptions

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Say I want to create a sorted dictionary (using `OrderedDict`), based on a rather complex operation on the values:

```
sorting_function = lambda x: x[1][0]
my_dictionary    = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dictionary.items(), key=sorting_function))
```

The problem with the code above is that, as I have it now, for some keys, my dictionary holds the value `None`, so the lambda operator throws an exception.

I would like these entries to be placed **last** in my dictionary, but I don't know how to modify my lambda function to handle exceptions. Do I need to resort to a full fledged function for this? Any thoughts?

#### Update:

To clarify, `x[1][0]` returns a string in my dictionary, when the entry is not `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lambda x: None if x[1] is None else x[1][0]
```

This actually puts the `None`s first since `None` seems to be less than anything. Hmm, that's interesting.

In Python 3, by default you can't compare objects of incompatible types. So for future-proofing you should instead substitute a value that can be compared with whatever type `x[1][0]` is. This approach will also work in Python 2.x, of course. For example, if it's numeric, you could use:

```
lambda x: float("+inf") if x[1] is None else x[1][0]
```

This will make the `None` values all sort to the end.

Evaluating `float("+inf")` for each `None` value is not optimal performance-wise; if this is a bottleneck, just define it once and use it in your lambda:

```
posinf = float("+inf")
lambda x: posinf if x[1] is None else x[1][0]
```

If it happens that `float("+inf")` can be a valid value for your data, then you will probably need a special class that always compares as greater than anything else:

```
class Maximus(object):
    "Object that is greater than any other object (but equal to itself)."
    __le__ = __eq__ = lambda self, other: isinstance(other, type(self))
    __ne__ = __gt__ = lambda self, other: not isinstance(other, type(self))
    __lt__ = lambda self, other: False      
    __ge__ = lambda self, other: True
    __str__  = lambda self: "I am the greatest!"
    __repr__ = lambda self: "Maximus()"

maximus = Maximus()

lambda x: maximus if x[1] is None else x[1][0]
```

(I believe that only `__lt__` and `__eq__` are required to be implemented for sorting to work, however `Maximus` has the full complement of comparison methods.)

Comment: `x` is a key/value pair.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute __getitem__` with the very first option (Python 2.7.4)

Comment: Wait, what exactly can be `None` here? It's the `x[1]` that can be `None` I bet, not the `x`. Updated.

Comment: The function `sorting_function` is applied on `items()` so `x[1]` holds the `value` (not the key) of the entry (this is what can be `None` in my dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

```
def sort_key(item):
    key, value = item
    return (value is None, value[0] if value is not None else None)
```

You could stuff this into a lambda if you really wanted to, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider "asking for permission": `lambda x: x[1][0] if x is not None else None`.

However, if you foresee your function getting more complex, you might consider making it a full fledged function:

```
def mySortingFunction(x):
    # do stuff

my_dictionary = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dictionary.items(), key=mySortingFunction)
```

Comment: Hmm, see my comment to @kindall, I am getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute __getitem__` with `lambda x: None if x is None else x[1][0]` (Python 2.7.4). I also updated the OP with info about the dictionary.

Comment: I have a feeling you are getting that error for some other reason. I just checked, and the comparator works, both in 2.7 and in 3.3

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a ternary operator in your lambda:

```
lambda x:x[1][0] if x[1][0] else 0
```